# My VSCode produces the exact same output in the terminal regardless of what code I run. The output is from previous code I have worked on

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code, filesystems

My VSCode produces the same output in the terminal regardless of the (python) code that I run. Every time, the output is the same and corresponds with a piece of code that I was working on about a week ago. That code began by asking the user to enter the day of the week. Every time I run ANY Python code, I am greeted by the query to enter a "day of the week".

I ran this issue by my CS professor (I am taking an intro CS course for non-CS students), and she was not able to diagnose the problem either. I am on a Windows 11 machine, if that makes any difference.

I have deleted the file of which VSCode keeps referring to, reinstalled Python, reinstalled VSCode, and uninstalled other Visual Studio software that I had on my computer for a personal project.

Running any Python file results in the terminal saying that the correct file path is being referred to, but the actual output printed is of the aforementioned "old code" and does not match the actual file being run. I have had issues in the past with VSCode interacting with files in OneDrive where edits in the IDE would not be reflected in the file (even after saving). I circumvented this issue by moving all of my Python files locally (as well as most of my other files as well).

I am absolutely stumped at what could be causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

This is what outputs in my terminal (not an error message):

PS C:\Users\sulev> & "C:/Program Files/Python312/python.exe" c:/Documents/CS_303E/for_loops_Demonstration_2.8.24.py
What day is the movie?

File changes have been saved before running. I am running my files by clicking the "run" button in the top-righthand corner of VSCode. Running print("Hello") via commandline results in the following error: "Unable to initialize device PRN".

Comment: Past the error message in your description

Comment: any pycache still remaining? are you saving your file changes before running? _how_ exactly are you running your files? what if you run via commandline?